# Batch request with youtube api - get the latest video information from multiple channels

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, http-post

I have 10 youtube channels that I like and I want to get the latest video information for each channel. Right now i'm doing 10 different calls like this one:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERNAME/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&start-index=1&max-results=1
```

I want to replace those 10 calls with a single one by using a batch request.

I tryed this:

```
String xml = "<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch'>" +
             "    <batch:operation type='query'/>" +
             "    <entry>" +
             "        <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID_1</id>" +
             "    </entry>" +
             "    <entry>" +
             "        <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID_2</id>" +
             "    </entry>" +
             ...
             "    <entry>" +
             "        <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID_10</id>" +
             "    </entry>" +
             "</feed>";

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/batch?v=2");
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(xml);
se.setContentType("text/xml");
httpPost.setEntity(se);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

I'm getting a XML with usefull data in the HTTPResponse object.

But if I want to get the 10 latest videos information, I won't know the videoId.

Does anybody know how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make a batch request that includes 10 different `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERNAME/uploads?v=2` URLs in the request body.

You would need to request `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERNAME/uploads?v=2&max-results=1` 10 times, once with each `USERNAME`.

Alternatively, if you have some sort server-side process that's interested in finding out when new videos are uploaded to a given channel, you can use either [PubSubHubbub](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/10/pubsubhubbub-for-youtube-activities.html) or [SUP](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_sup) to handle that scenario more efficiently. Because your question was tagged with `android` I'm assuming that you care about doing this client-side, though.